# Google App Maker, importing and opening an existing web page onLoad

Tags: hyperlink, google-app-maker

A newbie is trying to import [the following existing URL with curriculum changes](http://www.2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/Stundu_izmainas2.php). The page needs to open onLoad, instead of user clicking. 
So far, I have tried:

1. Link widget - only works, when one clicks on the link. Does not suit.
2. HTML widget - throws an error.
3. Fixed panel. Thought it was analogous to iframe. It isn't.
4. Tried adding a script 
   `function openWebsite() {
   window.open('http://www.2vsk.liepaja.edu.lv/Stundu_izmainas2.php','_blank');
   }` 
   No errors, but the screen is blank.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to open the link in a separate window? it yes, is that when the app loads or when a specific page loads? if not, that means you want to embed the page inside appmaker?

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone bother with embedding an existing website, Google provided the following solution.
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/html-iframe/

My case is a miss, since, as Google supports replied, the website has to have SSL certificate which my organization doesn't have.